# My logged in status is being maintained 36 hours after initial login on an online account

Tags: web-application, session-management

Log in time outs can be a pain we all know. However maintaining "logged in" status whereby even if I refresh a previously open tab the next day (I hibernate my laptop each night so Chrome does not get shut down) I have full access to my personal details account numbers etc.

Clearly this is not correct. What UK regulations will the UK Building Society have breached in allowing this to occur?

I don't wish for this failure to be swept under the carpet hence a desire to report what I assume is bad/incompetent practice.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a regulation that dictates session lengths?

Comment: Not certain  for Uk hence my question. Time outs on online banking appear to have been universal since I first used online accounts over  25 years ago and clearly  are designed to protect users account and data. A google search befire i posted found a regulation for the U.S that mandated them.

Comment: What regulation is that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official rule. Just best practice.

OWASP provides best practice recommendations:
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#session-expiration

And GDPR will suggest that "appropriate measures are taken". Aside from that, there isn't much.

Answer (score 1):

Having a single rule for a session timeout independent of the specific use cases makes no sense.

Which security measures are necessary depend on what needs to be protected and on the threats. For example online banking requires obviously stronger security measures than ordering some food because there is much more at stake.  And since stronger security often conflicts with better user experience, choosing the appropriate level is a trade-off one must consider for the specific use case.

Also, session timeout should not be viewed in isolation, since it is often not the only measure to protect access to an account. A session might be bound to a device, so that a stolen session cannot be reused on a different device. It might be bound on some kind of location, so that using it from somewhere else might require a new login. One might be able to distinguish between a private device (like a smartphone) and a shared device (public computer) and keep a larger session timeout for the private device since there is less risk of misuse etc.

Comment: Thanks for this. In this case it is a UK building Soceity which provide  savings accounts mortgages  in the same way as banks do but does not provide current account facilities. So withdrawals can be made payment details edited and personal profile info is all avaialble when logged in.. I take your points about alternative levels of protection  and these may exist but over the years and being an online user of many financila serviices providers I have never discovered this issue. But according to an earlier answer they may not have broken any rules just not followed best practice..